# Android library with custom dialog based on material theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-library, android-dialog

I’m building an `Android` sdk/library which has a custom `Dialog` which the host app can show

I chose to use `MaterialTheme` for my dialog to have ability to use modern `Widgets` and potentially for easy handling of `dark/light theme` changes in future but when host app used `AppCompat` theme in their `Activity` from which the dialog gets called, the app crashed because of theme mismatch.

Of course, as a library developer I want to cater to all kinds of apps using any kind of `Theme` declared in their app

- What's the right way of going forward with this ?
- Is this kind of limitation for a library project about using `Material` themes ?

Answer (score 0):

I’m thinking about moving my custom `Dialog` to use `AppCompat` theme with additional `New MaterialComponents attributes` defined in the theme in order to still use `Material theme` components in the library. it’s mentioned here https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/ under `AppCompat Themes` section

Not sure if that's the best way or only way!